# No simple group of order 4400

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Burnside proved, by use of character theory, that if a finite group $G$ has a conjugacy class $C$ such that $\vert C \vert$ is a prime power $> 1$, then $G$ is not simple. Let us call this statement "Burnside's non-simplicity theorem".

Let $G$ be a group of order $4400$. Let $n_{5}(G)$ denote the number of Sylow $5$-subgroups of $G$. In a proof that G is not simple, W.R. Scott (12.3.5, p. 335) uses  Burnside's non-simplicity theorem, and thus character theory (since Scott proves Burnside's non-simplicity theorem by use of character theory), in the case where $n_{5}(G) = 11$. He settles the other cases without character theory.

In fact, if I'm not wrong, it is not very difficult to avoid character theory, by use of the following lemma:

(Edit : the following lemma is the result of an improvement made by j.p. to my initial formulation.)

**Lemma.** Let $H$ be a finite group, let $p$ be a prime divisor of  $\vert H \vert$. Let $n_{p}(H)$ denote the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$. Assume that

1° $n_{p}(H)$ is the least divisor $d$ of $\vert H \vert$ such that $d > 1$ and $d \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$;

2°  $n_{p}(H) \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p^{r}}$, where $p^{r}$ denotes the greatest power of $p$ that divides $\vert H \vert$ (in other words, $p^{r}$ is the order of the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$).

Then $H$ is not simple.

*Proof.* In view of a strong form of the Sylow congruence theorem, we conclude from hypothesis 2° that we can choose two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$, say $P$ and $Q$, such that $P \cap Q > 1$.
We may additionally assume that $P\cap Q$ is maximal among the intersection of two Sylow $p$-subgroups. Let $N:=N_H(P\cap Q)$ be the normalizer of this intersection in $H$. As $P$ and $Q$ are (finite) $p$-groups, $N\cap P$ and $N\cap Q$ both properly contain $P\cap Q$. $N\cap P$ and $N\cap Q$ are contained in Sylow $p$-subgroups $P'$ rsp. $Q'$ of $N$, which in turn are contained in Sylow $p$-subgroups $P''$ rsp. $Q''$ of $H$.
By maximality of $P\cap Q$ we get $P=P''$ and $Q=Q''$ and hence that $N\cap P = P'$ and $N\cap Q = Q'$ are (different) Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N$,
thus $N$ has more than one Sylow $p$-subgroup. On the other hand, by Sylow theorems, the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N$ is $\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and divides $\vert N\vert$, which divides $\vert H \vert$. Thus the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N$ is $> 1$, is $\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and divides  $\vert H \vert$. By minimality of $n_{p}(H)$ (hypothesis 1°),

(*) the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N$ is $\geq n_{p}(H)$.

As $P\cap Q$ is normal in $N$, every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$ contains $P\cap Q$. But, as by the maximality of $P\cap Q$ every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$ is contained in a unique different Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$, by (*) every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ contains some Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$, and hence $P\cap Q$. Thus the intersection of all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$, which is a normal subgroup, is non-trivial, and thus $H$ is not simple.

Applying this lemma with $H = G$ (where $\vert G \vert = 4400$) and $p = 5$, we find that if $n_{5}(G) = 11$, then $G$ is not simple. Thus, in each case, it can be proved without character theory that a group of order $4400$ is not simple.

In exerc. 12.3.10, p. 337, W.R. Scott asks for a proof that there are no simple groups of order $1200$, $2240$ or $2800$. I presume that use of Burnside's non-simplicity theorem is expected, but here again, if I'm not wrong, character theory can be skipped.

My question is : do you know a nonzero natural number $n$ with at least $3$ distinct prime factors such that

(i) it is relatively easy to prove that there is no simple group of order $n$ with use of  Burnside's non-simplicity theorem;

(ii) it is not easy to prove it without Burnside's non-simplicity theorem and without character theory ?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: This will certainly apply to numbers of the form $p^aq^b$ for primes $p,q$ and sufficiently large $a$ and $b$.  You could consider numbers of the form $2^a3^b$ and find the smallest $a,b$ such that you cannot easily prove non-simplicity without Burnside's theorem. (There is a proof of Burnside's theorem that does not use character theory, but it is long and difficult.)

Comment: @Derek Holt As I said, I would be interested by a number $n$ with at least $3$ distinct prime factors...

Comment: You do not need the first assumption of your lemma, if you modify your proof a bit. I don't write now how, for not spoiling your fun finding it out on your own.

Comment: Life is short. I will read your proof with pleasure.

Comment: @j.p. In your edit, I don't understand this argument : "By maximality of $P \cap Q$, we get $P = P''$ and $Q = Q''$." May I ask for a bit elaboration ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. Both $P$ and $P''$ contain $P\cap N$ and thus $P\cap P''$ properly contains $P\cap Q$. As both $P$ and $P''$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$, by maximality of $P\cap Q$, both have to be equal. Any other gaps?

Comment: @j.p. Thanks and OK, no other problem. Do you know if your formulation of the lemma is somewhere in the literature ?

Comment: No, but looking at the normalizer of a maximal intersection of $p$-Sylows shouldn't be uncommon. As the lemma is mostly useful for proving that there are no simple groups of a small given order, I would expect to find it only in text books or really old articles. Your version is your own creation?

Comment: @j.p. Yes my version is "my own creation", but it was difficult not to fall on it when reading the proof given by W.R. Scott. Scott also uses commutativity and also reasons on the intersection of two p-Sylow subgroups. Your improvement is important, I think.